# I want to store input in array. and print the array elements but cout line isn't working

Tags: c++

> I am new in programming,

> basically in this program, it takes input from user and storing in array, 5 elements. After loop ends it should give the elements back but it seems that the last line is not working.

```
include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int size=5; 
string guess[size];
for (int i=0; i<size;i++){
    cin>>guess[size];
}
cout<<guess[size];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You used a for loop to populate the array (get input), why not use a for loop to print the array as well (display output)?

Comment: Hint: you need a loop for printing, just like you needed for reading.

Comment: What do you mean by " give the elements back"? do you want to print all the elements in the array?

Answer (score 1):

`guess[size]` is out of bounds. The last valid index in an array with `size` elements is `size-1`. Further, `string guess[size];` is not valid C++ when `size` is not a constant expression. At the very least it should be `const int size = 5;`. You wrote a loop to take input and you also need a loop to print all elements.

This is the correct loop to read the input:

```
const int size=5; 
std::string guess[size];
for (int i=0; i < size; i++){
    std::cin >> guess[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify it so that both input and output should use i as the loop subscript.

```
//cover #
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int size=5;
    string guess[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size;i++){
        cin>>guess[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout<<guess[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Range based Loops when You want to Print whole array, so you won't get an "Out-Of-Bounds" error. Because the Index in array are Zero Based Always remember the last index is (length_of_array - 1)

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int size = 5;
    string guess[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        cin >> guess[i];
    }
    // range based loop
    for (int i : guess)
    {
        cout << i << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```